# Why my pdf files are not opening when I download from onedrive

Tags: onedrive, insider-preview, pdf

From one drive I have downloaded my pdf files to sd drive and I am trying to open using pdf reader but,it is showing unable to open and the file size is showing 0KB.But in one drive the file size is 6.37MB.

Please suggest me.

Comment: Which PDF Reader app are you using?

Comment: Have the files been downloaded fully? What is it's size in File app.